# Monodevelop convert iPhone to iPhone Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, storyboard, monodevelop, xib

My project is a iPhone project on MonoDevelop.

I created a Main.storyboard and chose it as main storyboard from XCode .But my selection disappears then. I also select a main interface but no way.

Is there any easy way changing type between xib type and storyboard type?

Answer (score 1):

On MonoDevelop project options. 
Under Build section there is iPhone application section. 
Under iPhone / iPod Deployment Info Chose my storyboard name as Main interface solved the issue.

But its still empty in XCode.It doesn't matter.